# RELLENAR Checkbox por defecto en JSF

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, xhtml

No sé cómo hacerlo.
La única forma que tengo es esta:

public void onNodeSelect(ValueChangeEvent event) {

```
    Boolean selected = (Boolean) event.getNewValue();
    Long odmId = (Long)((UIInput) event.getSource()).getAttributes().get(ODM_ID);

    if(selected){       
        listOdmIds.add(odmId);      
    }else{
        listOdmIds.remove(odmId);
    }

}
```

Quiero que estén seleccionados automáticamente.

Aquí dejo el xhtml:

```
    <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <!-- Arbol de Odms -->
                            <p:treeTable id="odmTreeTable" value="#{statisticsBean.root}"
                                var="node" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="300"
                                expandMode="true"
                                selection="#{statisticsBean.lSelectedOdmHeaderDTO}"
                                emptyMessage="No hay datos">

                                <p:column headerText="ODM" style="width: 60%;text-align: left;">
                                    <h:outputText
                                        style="font-weight:#{node.cedistName eq null ? 'bold' : 'normal'}"
                                        value="#{node.name}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Seleccionar" styleClass="text-center"
                                    style="width: 20%">


                                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkTreeTable" disabled="#{empty statisticsBean.messageType}"
                                        value="#{node.selected}"
                                        rendered="#{node.cedistName eq null ? false : true}"
                                        valueChangeListener="#{statisticsBean.onNodeSelect}">
                                        <f:attribute name="odmId" value="#{node.id}" />
                                        <p:ajax event = "change" global="true" update=":form:odmTreeTable" />
                                    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>



                                </p:column>
                            </p:treeTable>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Por favor, añade un poco más de código tanto del XHTML y de Java donde estes realizando esa comprobación.

Comment: @NeoChiri editado

Comment: Si he entendido bien lo que quieres decir, quieres que el checkbox muestre un valor por defecto, para poder hacer eso debes hacer que el atributo del bean que le da valor tenga el valor por defecto que tu desees, en este caso es ´#{node.select}´ pues en el bean solo debes darle el valor ´true´ o ´false´ que tu quieras que tenga por defecto; si no es así, por favor elabora un poco más lo que quieres saber.

Comment: @NeoChiri Sí eso esta bién, pero luego al deselecionar uno me quita todos los check, no me quita de uno en uno.

Comment: Entonces por favor incluye todo el código que involucra esa acción, porque en el XHTML solo se muestra uno mientras que tu hablas de varios, y en el código Java se ve como quitas o añades elementos a una lista que no se ve que función tiene.

Comment: @NeoChiri Buenos días, ahí dejo el código entero del xhtml